# What causes this strange result in Python when assigning to values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, variable-assignment

I recently reduced a bug in some code to being a result of the following behaviour:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros(10)
>>> value = 0
>>> dictionary = {"key":[arr,value]}
>>> dictionary["key"][0]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> dictionary["key"][1]
0
>>> dictionary["key"][0]+=1
>>> dictionary["key"][1]+=1
>>> dictionary["key"][0]   
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> dictionary["key"][1]   
1
>>> arr
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> value
0
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> dictionary["key"][0] is arr
True
>>> dictionary["key"][1] is value 
False
```

Probably a silly question, but what causes this?

Comment: `np.array` objects are mutable, `int` objects aren't. Adding to an integer really creates a new object, adding to an array updates the old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of the numpy array, you have the *same* object assigned with the name `arr` and inside your dictionary. As such, when you modify it you see the change appear for both, they're the same object after all, and numpy arrays are *mutable*.

For the integer, when you do `dictionary["key"][1]+=1` you are creating a new integer inside the dictionary, this is because integers are *immutable* [1]. This means that the two integers (`value` and `dictionary["key"][1]`) are different objects, and so one is modified but the other is not.

*[1] It might look like `x = 2; x += 1` is operating on the same object, after all `+=` should do "in-place" operations, but it's not because of the immutability. Behind the scenes you're actually re-binding `x` with a new integer object, as such they have the same name, but are different objects.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies with the difference between a numpy array (mutable) and an integer (immutable).  When you performed this:

```
dictionary["key"][0]+=1
```

This mutated the numpy array in-place, and is therefore still the same object.

When you performed this:

```
dictionary["key"][1]+=1
```

That cannot mutate an integer in-place (being immutable), and therefore allocated a new object (which is why `is` returns `False`).